# CSS and JS Coming from HTTPS on an HTTPS site

Tags: magento-1.9

In My website when i activate https,all url is coming from http instead of https.

I have tried to debug the same and found out that the url generated by

```
$designPackage->getSkinUrl($name, array());
```

in **app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php**

I am unable to find what is the issue when we try host website on https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amit's answer is correct. However there is an interesting quirk about `Mage::getBaseUrl` which is that you can force it to give an HTTPS link always:

In your code you're doing:

```
$designPackage->getSkinUrl($name, array());
```

However if you add the `_secure` parameter as `true` you can force an HTTPS link:

```
$designPackage->getSkinUrl($name, array('_secure'=>true));
```

Note that this will only output the base url for the HTTPS url set in `System > Configuration > Web` as Amit has pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

As you have active https ,then You need to change some setting at backed.

Goto **admin>system>Configuration> General>Web>** Change all Secure `urls(media,skin etc )` and  `Unsecure  Url (media,skin etc )`  **To https from http.**

If backend is not opened then go to your Magento DB select ***core_config_data*** table change all where

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%base%url%';
```

from http to https